# How to decode the syntax table to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to decode the following syntax in PHP array:

```
{

'Property': {

'Lang', 'en'

, 'Make': function () {

// Do something

}
}

}
```

where the value of "`Make`" is of type `string`

Finally getting a table like:

```
echo $ array ['property'] [ 'lang']; // String

echo $ array ['property'] [ 'Make']; // String
```

PLEASE : It's not a standard JSON that I use, See well the `Make` Property.

Comment: you need to decode the json value

Comment: `json_decode` can not decode the `make` property with `function`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the function **json_decode()?** You can read more about it here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: `json_decode` can not decode the `make` property with `function`

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode(); in your code.

```
json_decode($json_result);
```

"**$json_result**" your data in json type.

For your knowledge
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: `json_decode` can not decode the `make` property with `function`. It's not a standard JSON that I use